# NoMethodError: undefined method for foreign key - Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, foreign-keys, nomethoderror

This is the error I got.

```
UserFriendshipTest#test_that_creating_a_friendship_works_without_raising_an_exception:
NoMethodError: undefined method `friend' for #<UserFriendshipTest:0x2947dd0>
    test/models/user_friendship_test.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in <class:UserFriendshipTest>'
    test/models/user_friendship_test.rb:8:in `block in <class:UserFriendshipTest>'
```

This is my user_friendship_test.rb code.

```
require 'test_helper'
class UserFriendshipTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
    should belong_to(:user)
    should belong_to(:friend)

    test "that creating a friendship works without raising an exception" do
        assert_nothing_raised do 
            UserFriendship.create user: users(:brijesh), friend: friend(:neha)
        end
    end
end
```

And this is my user_friendship.rb

```
class UserFriendship < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :friend, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "friend_id"
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, problem is in following lines, you are trying to create friendship with `friend: friend(:neha)`, you should use create friend with `users(:neha)` :-

```
assert_nothing_raised do 
  UserFriendship.create user: users(:brijesh), friend: users(:neha)
end
```

Thanks

Comment: assert_nothing_raised is not being picked up as an assertion. Any idea why?

Comment: I don't know, but I wouldn't recommend using assert_nothing_raised, because it actually doesn't test anything. http://www.thagomizer.com/blog/2013/06/08/assert-nothing-raised.html

Comment: And if you are using Ruby version 2.0, I don't think, it doesn't support it as well.

Comment: http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/test/unit/rdoc/Test/Unit/Assertions.html#method-i-assert_nothing_raised - support seems to be there.